# Why can't I specify the fill color at the top level of ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>% 
  filter(manufacturer == "dodge") %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(cyl, -n), n), fill = "blue") +  # line 5
  geom_col() + 
  # geom_col(fill = "blue") + 
  NULL
```

The code I commented out above will fill my bar chart columns with a blue color. However, the code as shown above does not fill my columns with a blue color. Why not? Didn't I properly specify that all aesthetics should be filled blue in that fifth line of code?

[image: geom_col() fill color]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation of `?ggplot`, the ellipsis argument reads: "Other arguments passed on to methods. Not currently used.". Aesthetic mappings are provided inside `aes()` calls, either in layers or in the main ggplot call.

It is relevant to differentiate aesthetic mappings from simply aesthetics; what you are providing the main ggplot call as `"fill = blue"` is an aesthetic whereas `aes(reorder(cyl, -n), n)` is an aesthetic mapping (since it maps input data to a coordinate on the x- and y-axes). The main ggplot call accepts aesthetic mappings but not aesthetics. Layers accept both of them. The aesthetic is accepted through the ellipsis parameter, which is then passed down to the relevant geom or stat. Of course, if you could provide the main ggplot call with simple aesthetics, then this would have to be for all layers simultaneously, which I would suspect goes a bit against what the grammar of graphics orthodoxy is trying to achieve.

There is a way to set an aesthetic to a geom without having to specify it in the layer generator itself, and that is by updating the defaults.

```
update_geom_defaults("col", list(fill = "blue"))

mpg %>% 
  filter(manufacturer == "dodge") %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(cyl, -n), n)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this will change it for all subsequent `geom_col()` plots that you make and may even retroactively affect plots that you have stored under a variable. However, I don't know exactly know what you would like to gain by not specifying a variable in the layer.